# Display content dynamic from xml file in zip folder

Tags: c#, xml, zip

I´m coding in C# and I have a project that the user will 
be able to upload a .zip file and in that file will a .xml be read 
and chapters based on xml tags will de displayed dynamic.

Right now it is hardcoded a specific file and in that  file 
that specific .xml file.

How do I read .xml file from a zip file and display that dynamic in C#?

Comment: Well, first you'll need to unzip your file (a tutorial can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)) and then search for a .xml file and read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft documentation has an exemple on this. Extracting specific file from a zip Archive and unzip them in a directory: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files#example-2-extract-specific-file-extensions.

Then you next step will be to process the all or some file from the directory, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_

If you don't want to unzip, you can directly open the ZipArchiveEntry, with : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open?view=netframework-4.7.2

With multiple Xml files in the zip all serialisation of `myType`the codes should boil down to :

```
string zipPath = @".\result.zip";
List<myType> listResults ;

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myType);
    listResults = 
        archive
            .Entries
            .Where(entry => entry.FullName
                                 .EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Select(entry => (myType)serializer.Deserialize(entry.Open()))
            .ToList();
}
```

For any missing reference in your project follow the light bulb !

Answer (score 0):

Add the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly to your project references. Once you did that, you can open an archive like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var zipPath = "Path-To-Your-Zipfile";

    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        var xmlFile = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FullName.EndsWith(".xml"));

        if(xmlFile == null)
            return;

        using (var stream = xmlFile.Open())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```